# Scrapy CrawlSpider stop execution during __init__

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a CrawlSpider based on the python Scrapy 2.0.1 framework. During initialisation, the spider is configured before execution. There are points in this initialisation where I would like the spider to halt execution as it is improperly configured.

I can output to the logger, but I would then like to stop the initialisation or indicate to the spider to not execute. How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrapy spider add health check before starting spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60461028/scrapy-spider-add-health-check-before-starting-spider)

Comment: I will have a look @Gallaecio thank you, it does seem a bit odd that this mechanism is not available without this 'hack'. At the moment the only thing I can do is raise an exception, which results in bad feedback to the user